# loop in array in JSON using typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

i wanna loop for subjects array in JSON response

JSON Response :

```
{
"$id": "1",
"Council_ID": 116,
"number": "67",
"subjects": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "subjectCode": "67",
        "type": 4,
    },
    {
        "$id": "3",
        "subjectCode": "67",
        "type": 4,
    }
   ]
}
```

model.component.ts:

```
this.dataStorageService.storeSubjects(newSubject, this.meetingID)
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.dataStorageService.getCouncilId(this.meetingID).subscribe(response => {
                this.subjectsWithID = response.json();
                this.sublength = this.subjectsWithID.subjects.length;
                console.log(this.sublength);
                for(let i = 0 ; i <= this.sublength; i++){
                    this.typee = this.subjectsWithID.subjects[i].type;
                    this.dataStorageService.getSubjectTypeId(this.typee).subscribe(response =>{
                        this.namesOfSub = Array.of( response.json());
                        console.log(this.namesOfSub)
                    });
                }
                // console.log(this.typee, 'bla bla');
            });
            this.addSubjectForm.reset();
            this.router.navigate(['/model']);
            return true;
```

That give me error : - Property 'subjects' does not exist on type 'any[]'. there is any suggestion to get rid of this error ?

Comment: show how you declared subjectsWithID

Comment: are you using httpClient??

Comment: @Sajeetharan subjectsWithID show me this Json Response i posted

Comment: @FatehMohamed yes

Comment: sorry , subjectsWithID  = []; that my declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok using httpClient , you can't get the property this.subjectsWithID.subjects, but usinh http it is possible, it's because httpClinet when it parse the result it does know the share of your object, you have to give a type for your result or you can access your property like this:

```
  this.subjectsWithID['subjects']
```

or you can specify the type using interface :

```
    return this.http.get<myObject>(...url)

 interface Sidebar {
    id: number;
    Council_ID: number,
    number: number,
    subjects: [...
  }
```

Comment: but now give me error Cannot read property 'type' of undefined  in console??

Comment: when using this:  this.subjectsWithID['subjects'] ?

Comment: it should work , weird, the best solution is to define a type for your results using interfaces